# Why does it say my parameter has no argument?

Tags: c#

I am a new C# student and just started working on object oriented programming. I am using visual studio and I am getting error code CS7036: there is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'keywords' of Book.Book. Trying to make it so it outputs the book information.

below is my main code...

```
using System;

namespace BookProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Book newBook = new Book("Orson Scott Card, Enders Game, Science Fiction, January 15th 1985", 0812550706);
            Console.WriteLine(newBook.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

... and here is the class code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BookProgram
{
    public class Book
    {
        private string _author;
        private string _title;
        private string _keywords;
        private string _publicationDate;
        private int _isbn;


        public Book()
        {
            _author = "";
            _title = "";
            _keywords = "";
            _publicationDate = "";
            _isbn = 0;
        }

        public Book(string author, string title, string keywords, string publicationDate, int isbn)
        {
            _author = author;
            _title = title;
            _keywords = keywords;
            _publicationDate = publicationDate;
            _isbn = isbn;
        }

        public string Author { get => _author; set => _author = value; }
        public string Title { get => _title; set => _title = value; }
        public string Keywords { get => _keywords; set => _keywords = value; }
        public string PublicationDate { get => _publicationDate; set => _publicationDate = value; }
        public int ISBN { get => _isbn; set => _isbn = value; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("AUTHOR: " + Author + " TITLE: " + Title + " KEYWORDS: " + Keywords + " PUBLICATION DATE: "
                   + PublicationDate + " ISBN: " + ISBN);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your constructor is defined to take 5 parameters, yet you only pass 2 (1 string, 1 number). You must pass 4 strings, 1 number.

Comment: You are passing *one* string, that happens to contain commas; you need to pass *multiple* strings, *separated* by commas

Comment: also note: integers don't "contain" leading zeros; if the leading zero is significant in `0812550706`, then: use a string, not an integer; in the same way that `5`, `05`, `005` and `00000000005` are all just: five - there aren't different versions of "five"

Comment: I looked it up; ISBNs exist in 10-digit and 13-digit variants (the last digit is a checksum); as such it would be *very* brave (read: "foolish") to use `int` for ISBN, since that only covers a tiny range of the possible values (it mostly covers things published before 2007 in English). Personally, I'd use `string`, but I guess `long` would work if you want.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'd suggest an ISBN could be a structure with small integers for publisher, title and an optional EAN and a byte for group. The check digit could be generated. However, its probably more complicated than that and way beyond the scope of the question. As you say, a string would likely suffice here.

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
Book newBook = new Book("Orson Scott Card, Enders Game, Science Fiction, January 15th 1985", 0812550706);
```

with

```
Book newBook = new Book("Orson Scott Card", "Enders Game", "Science Fiction", "January 15th 1985", 0812550706);
```

otherwise it's just passed as one string + one integer instead of the 5 required parameters

and you should think about using `DateTime` type for `publicationDate` and `string` type for `isbn`

Comment: Ohhh. Ha. I was looking at this for so long trying to figure out what it meant. Thank you!